# Magento 2 pagination is not working in join with product collection and custom table

Tags: pagination, magento2

```
$page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;

$pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 4;

$collection = $this->productcollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect(array('group_name','name','status'));

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);

$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(['firmware_product' => $collection->getTable('firmware_product')],'firmware_product.product_id = e.entity_id',[]);
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(['firmware' => $collection->getTable('firmware')],'firmware.entity_id = firmware_product.firmware_id',[])
    ->columns(array("firmware.version_no","firmware.build_date","firmware.is_active"));


$collection->getSelect()->where("firmware.is_active = ?",1);

$collection->getSelect()->order('firmware.entity_id', 'DESC');

$collection->setPageSize($pageSize);$collection->setCurPage($page);
```

The code above gives me the same `entity_id` as already exists. I reset the column and fetch only the firmware records and it still gives me  the same error in the firmware `entity_id`. If I use this code

```
 $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

then the pagination does not work. Can anyone tell me what the solution for this is?

Comment: hope this help 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130405/how-to-add-pagination-on-custom-collection-in-magento-2

Comment: Thanks Lalit ! custom collection paging is working fine. The problem after applying join with product collection. Then it is not working ..

Comment: Did you find solution?